# Can't login to Magento backend 'No region found within the locale 'de''

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have moved a Magento installation from a preview system to my local machine for developing and testing.

i have setup the BASE URL to my V-Host in the database.

The frontend works but i cant get into the admin panel.

if i log in, i got the following error message:

```
No region found within the locale 'de'

Trace:
#0 /var/www/myProjectName/lib/Zend/Currency.php(101): Zend_Currency->setLocale(NULL)
#1 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(575): Zend_Currency->__construct('USD', NULL)
#2 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('EUR')
#3 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(216): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(NULL, Array)
#4 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(197): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision(NULL, 2, Array, true, false)
#5 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(82): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format(NULL)
#6 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->format(NULL)
#7 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php(74): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->addTotal('Revenue', NULL)
#8 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals->_prepareLayout()
#9 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#10 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#11 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#12 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#13 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#14 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#15 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#16 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#18 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#19 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#20 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#21 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#22 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#23 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /var/www/myProjectName/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 /var/www/myProjectName/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 /var/www/myProjectName/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

Can i set the region anywhere? everything i found with google cant help me out.
Just tell me what else you want to know.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks smo

Answer (score 1):

So basically:
got to core_config_data in your database
and delete the line where path = general

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but there was no "general" Config-Entry without any other path and content, so i need to debug the problem a bit deeper.

Btw - you can search the config-entry like this:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE core_config_data.path = 'general';
```

To me, it seems to be a Firefox-only Problem and i think, its out of the language-setting from the browser. Its inside the Zend-currency-handling. Only Firefox has the problem - Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer works well!

So i fixed the Magento-Code like that a bit dirty but it works:

Copy `lib/Zend/Currency.php` to `app/code/local/Zend/Currency.php` and edit this.
Now you can overwrite the Zend-Framework file.

Go to the following line at copied:

```
public function setLocale($locale = null)
        #require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';
        try {
            $locale = Zend_Locale::findLocale($locale);
```

Add last Line:

```
public function setLocale($locale = null)
    {
        #require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';
        try {
            $locale = Zend_Locale::findLocale($locale);
            if ( $locale == 'de' ) $locale = 'de_DE';       // zend fix the firefox-locale error
```

After that, you can edit the products again!

This Variant is also updateable out of the overwrite-code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

It happens that the locale is defined based on your browser locale detection. You can like or not this behavior but in this case that's the reason you have this error message.

To fix that you have to change the priority or switch the locale supported by your browser. What I mean by priority is that the browser provide a list of supported language. For example you may have something like that `Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`

In your case it searches `de` but your browser doesn't support it. So you may use "Quick Locale" for firefox to switch to en-US or de-DE for example to prevent such errors if you use this one or something similar. It's not a but in Magento, it's a wanted behavior I think.

Comment: You may have set the locale variable wrong in Magento's core_config_data which is where it checks for the default locale.

Comment: @JoshRibakoff of course, but his problem is due to a browser detection problem not a config problem. If I did an answer based on the browser detection, it's due to the error trace in the question and his backend problem. If you follow the trace, you will find there is a browser fallback detection in Zend Framework. So my answer is based on the specific problem of the question's author. If it was a locale config problem, why he has no problem in frontend? The config locale is for frontend or when emulating frontend behavior in backend. I did analyze before to answer.

Comment: I had his same error, it was the core_config_data setting for me. Not the browser. Not sure about his problem.